# Print data.frame structure as character

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
    y = c(0.348, 0.099, 0.041, 0.022, 0.015, 0.010, 0.007, 0.005, 0.004, 0.003),
    x = c(458, 648, 694, 724, 756, 790, 818, 836, 848, 876))
```

When I print the `data.frame` I (obviously) get this output:

```
df
#        y   x
# 1  0.348 458
# 2  0.099 648
# 3  0.041 694
# 4  0.022 724
# 5  0.015 756
# 6  0.010 790
# 7  0.007 818
# 8  0.005 836
# 9  0.004 848
# 10 0.003 876
```

Is there any function where I can print the `data.frame` as a `character string` (or similar)?

```
magic_function(df)
# output
"df <- data.frame(
 y = c(0.348, 0.099, 0.041, 0.022, 0.015, 0.010, 0.007, 0.005, 0.004, 0.003),
 x = c(458, 648, 694, 724, 756, 790, 818, 836, 848, 876))"
```

I literally want to print out something like `"df <- data.frame(x = c(...), y = (...))"` so that I can copy the output and paste it to a stackoverflow question (*for reproducibility*)!

Comment: Try dput(df) to do something like this.

Comment: You can easily assign this. e.g. 

df2 <- structure(list(y = c(0.348, 0.099, 0.041, 0.022, 0.015, 0.01, 
0.007, 0.005, 0.004, 0.003), x = c(458, 648, 694, 724, 756, 790, 
818, 836, 848, 876)), .Names = c("y", "x"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: by the way, it's not obvious that that's the output you get from printing your `data.frame` -- in fact, that's _not_ how `data.frame`s are printed in `base` R. That output comes from `dplyr` AFAIK

Comment: Also, why is it important that it is printed as character?

Comment: Regarding the justification: I just copy the `dput` output from the console. And of course, coding up a data.frame for a minimal reproducible example is preferable in my opinion. At least I prefer that in questions if the process of creating the object is not too complicated and doesn't require unrelated packages.

Comment: @mkt cleaned up the output (fresh session without dplyr loaded)

Comment: @mkt not exactly important that it's printed as a character.... I just thought any function might print it that way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had to do this recently. `deparse` will do the trick, and you can `paste` the multi-line output into a single string with `collapse`:

```
df.as.char <- paste(deparse(df), collapse = "")
df.as.char
# [1] "structure(list(y = c(0.348, 0.099, 0.041, 0.022, 0.015, 0.01, 0.007, 0.005, 0.004, 0.003), x = c(458, 648, 694, 724, 756, 790, 818, 836, 848, 876)), .Names = c(\"y\", \"x\"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = \"data.frame\")"
```

Depending on the size of your object, you might consider using the `width.cutoff` argument to `deparse` (which will reduce the number of lines created by `deparse`).

If you've got the same thing in mind that I did, then you can assign this through:

```
df.from.char <- eval(parse(text = df.as.char))
df.from.char
#    y   x
# 1  0.348 458
# 2  0.099 648
# 3  0.041 694
# 4  0.022 724
# 5  0.015 756
# 6  0.010 790
# 7  0.007 818
# 8  0.005 836
# 9  0.004 848
# 10 0.003 876
identical(df.from.char, df)
# [1] TRUE
```

And if you really need the assignment arrow to be part of the `character`, just `paste0` that in.

Comment: You could `deparse(df)`.

Comment: @Roland nice -- `deparse` is basically the same as `capture.output(dput())`, right?

Comment: No, I wouldn't say it is the same. `capture.output` creates a text connection and `sink`s to it. Presumably `deparse` is more efficient.

Comment: `deparse` also gives you more control, for instance you can specify the width of the output line.

Comment: @KonradRudolph just looking through the `deparse` documentation. Is the string output capped at 500?

Comment: @emehex No, that’s merely the line length limit.

Answer (score 0):

one option is to use:

```
  dput(df)
```

returns:

```
structure(list(y = c(0.348, 0.099, 0.041, 0.022, 0.015, 0.01, 
0.007, 0.005, 0.004, 0.003), x = c(458, 648, 694, 724, 756, 790, 
818, 836, 848, 876)), .Names = c("y", "x"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is @mkt 's comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got something!

```
df4so <- function(df) {
    # collapse dput
    # shout out to KonradRudolph, Roland and MichaelChirico
    a <- paste(capture.output(dput(df)), collapse = "")
    # remove structure junk
    b <- gsub("structure\\(list\\(", "", a)
    # remove everything after names
    c <- gsub("\\.Names\\s.*","",b)
    # remove trailing whitespace
    d <- gsub("\\,\\s+$", "", c)
    # put it all together
    e <- paste0('df <- data.frame(', d)
    # return
    print(e)
}

df4so(df)
```

Output:

```
 [1] "df <- data.frame(y = c(0.348, 0.099, 0.041, 0.022, 0.015, 0.01, 0.007, 0.005, 0.004, 0.003), x = c(458, 648, 694, 724, 756, 790, 818, 836, 848, 876))"
```

Suitable for copying and pasting to stackoverflow!

Comment: if all you're after is something to print to SO, `dput` should cover the job. perhapse see also the [`overflow`](https://github.com/mrdwab/overflow-mrdwab) package with facilities for switching between R usage and SO posting:

Comment: (in particular, we're happy with the `structure(list(...))`-type output that `dput` gives us -- we can still copy-paste that into R and work with your sample data.